# Dash adaptive playback with starting tracks, How to?

Tags: exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have 3 ways of playing a adaptive dash video in my app:

1. Fixed video and audio tracks
2. Adaptive video and audio tracks
3. Adaptive video and audio tracks (with starting track)

The first 2 ways work perfectly, however **the 3rd method behaves weird**.

What I'm doing is first setting the starting tracks on the 'onTracksChanged' method. As soon as the player calls the method onLoadingChanged(false) I want to remove the selection of the starting track and let the player select the optimal track. For removing the selected I'm calling trackSelector.clearSelectionOverrides(), but that completely removes the buffer and the video stops and starts buffering in the optimal track.

[image]

The behaviour I want to achieve **is the following**:

select startingt tracks (let's suppose 144p) -> load the first chunks -> remove the selection of 144p -> Keep playing the remaining buffer in 144p and start loading in the optimal track in the meantime.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with an AdaptiveTrackSelection and blacklist all tracks except those you want to keep. To bring that in place it seems easiest to provide your own TrackSelection.Factory.

```
public class StartupTrackSelectionFactory implements TrackSelection.Factory {

  // end blacklisting after ten seconds earliest
  private static final long BLACKLIST_DURATION = 10 * 1000;

  private final BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;

  public StartupTrackSelectionFactory(BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter) {
    this.bandwidthMeter = bandwidthMeter;
  }

  @Override
  public TrackSelection createTrackSelection(TrackGroup group, int... tracks) {
    AdaptiveTrackSelection adaptiveTrackSelection = new AdaptiveTrackSelection(
        group,
        tracks,
        bandwidthMeter,
        AdaptiveTrackSelection.DEFAULT_MAX_INITIAL_BITRATE,
        AdaptiveTrackSelection.DEFAULT_MIN_DURATION_FOR_QUALITY_INCREASE_MS,
        AdaptiveTrackSelection.DEFAULT_MAX_DURATION_FOR_QUALITY_DECREASE_MS,
        AdaptiveTrackSelection.DEFAULT_MIN_DURATION_TO_RETAIN_AFTER_DISCARD_MS,
        AdaptiveTrackSelection.DEFAULT_BANDWIDTH_FRACTION,
        AdaptiveTrackSelection.DEFAULT_BUFFERED_FRACTION_TO_LIVE_EDGE_FOR_QUALITY_INCREASE,
        AdaptiveTrackSelection.DEFAULT_MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_BUFFER_REEVALUTATION_MS,
        Clock.DEFAULT);

    int lowestBitrate = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int lowestBitrateTrackIndex = C.INDEX_UNSET;
    for (int i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
      Format format = group.getFormat(tracks[i]);
      if (format.bitrate < lowestBitrate) {
        lowestBitrateTrackIndex = i;
        lowestBitrate = format.bitrate;
      }
      adaptiveTrackSelection.blacklist(tracks[i], BLACKLIST_DURATION);
    }
    if (lowestBitrateTrackIndex != C.INDEX_UNSET) {
      adaptiveTrackSelection.blacklist(tracks[lowestBitrateTrackIndex], 0);
    }
    return adaptiveTrackSelection;
  }

}
```

Now when creating your DefaultTrackSelector you can pass that StartupTrackSelectionFactory and use it to create a player instance.

```
TrackSelection.Factory trackSelectionFactory = 
          new StartupTrackSelectionFactory(BANDWIDTH_METER);
trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory);
player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(renderersFactory, trackSelector);
```

If you want to keep your approach with listening for an onLoadChange event, you may want to initially put Long.MAX_VALUE as blacklist duration and then set the duration to 0 for all indices when onLoadChange is called.

Comment: Will check monday first in the morning and i’ll get back to you, thanks!

Comment: Hi again! I couldn't tackle this until now. I just tried your solution but it does not work for me. The param DEFAULT_MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_BUFFER_REEVALUTATION_MS & Clock.DEFAULT are not present in ExoPlayer 2.6.1. Maybe that's the problem. I also removed my previous code (clearSelectionOverrides etc...). Any idea?

Comment: I don't think these missing params are the reason for this not working for you. I'd still suggest to move to the most latest and greates version which is 2.7.1.

Comment: I am trying to set blacklisted tracks as you have done, but it's not working. CreateTrackSelection is not being called.

Comment: createTrackSelection is no more in TrackSelection.Factory, instead override createTrackSelections @marcbaechinger . Do you have any solution on the new changes?

Answer (score 1):

Since `createTrackSelection` method is removed from library, we can now directly implement `AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory()` and override `createAdaptiveTrackSelection` method of it and use @marcbaechinger's code.
Below is the kotlin version of it.

```
class SmoothTrackSelectionFactory(bandwidthMeter: DefaultBandwidthMeter) : AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory() {

    // end blacklisting after ten seconds earliest
    private val BLACKLIST_DURATION = (10 * 1000).toLong()

    private var bandwidthMeter: BandwidthMeter = bandwidthMeter

    override fun createAdaptiveTrackSelection(group: TrackGroup, bandwidthMeter: BandwidthMeter, tracks: IntArray, totalFixedTrackBandwidth: Int): AdaptiveTrackSelection {
        val adaptiveTrackSelection = AdaptiveTrackSelection(
                group,
                tracks,
                bandwidthMeter,
                Integer.MAX_VALUE.toLong(),
                AdaptiveTrackSelection.DEFAULT_MIN_DURATION_FOR_QUALITY_INCREASE_MS.toLong(),
                AdaptiveTrackSelection.DEFAULT_MAX_DURATION_FOR_QUALITY_DECREASE_MS.toLong(),
                AdaptiveTrackSelection.DEFAULT_MIN_DURATION_TO_RETAIN_AFTER_DISCARD_MS.toLong(),
                AdaptiveTrackSelection.DEFAULT_BANDWIDTH_FRACTION,
                AdaptiveTrackSelection.DEFAULT_BUFFERED_FRACTION_TO_LIVE_EDGE_FOR_QUALITY_INCREASE,
                AdaptiveTrackSelection.DEFAULT_MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_BUFFER_REEVALUTATION_MS,
                Clock.DEFAULT)
        var lowestBitrate = Int.MAX_VALUE
        var lowestBitrateTrackIndex = C.INDEX_UNSET
        for (i in tracks.indices) {
            val format: Format = group.getFormat(tracks[i])
            if (format.bitrate < lowestBitrate) {
                lowestBitrateTrackIndex = i
                lowestBitrate = format.bitrate
            }
            adaptiveTrackSelection.blacklist(tracks[i], BLACKLIST_DURATION)
        }
        if (lowestBitrateTrackIndex != C.INDEX_UNSET) {
            adaptiveTrackSelection.blacklist(tracks[lowestBitrateTrackIndex], 0)
        }
        return adaptiveTrackSelection
    }
}
```